# Does emergence or the second law create more degrees of freedom total?

Tags: thermodynamics, degrees-of-freedom, emergent-properties

Here's my layman thought process:

By emergence and the second law, new "modes" or points in configuration space become "unlocked" with macroscopic systems. One is a brain, which can have an experience or memory ontop of just being an assemblage of x microscopic particles.

The counter point might be that it takes x particles to make a brain with conscious experience, but x-1 particles to make a brain without. So we traded 1 degree of freedom in configuration space for another.

Is there anywhere to go with this idea? And where can I find out about if degrees of freedom are always there since the big bang, or being added (by this or by expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you consider 'emergent degrees of freedom' the macroscopic state of a brain has *vastly* fewer degrees of freedom than the microscopic state its constitutent particles.

Imagine picking a few hundred water molecules at random around the brain and giving them a small nudge. Will this have a noticeable effect on the state of the brain. Most likely then answer is no. Unless the molecule is in a particularly critical position or the nudge pushes it into somewhere water molecules normally shouldn't go your nudge will most likely be lost in with random thermal noise.

We can infact quantify exactly how much more information is present in the microstate than the microstate of the system. This is precisely the thermodynamic entropy of the system. So what you are proposing is essentially that the brain has a negative entropy. Now whilst a brain may not have the highest possible entropy for its constitutent parts (at a given temperature) its entropy certainly isn't negative.

Comment: I see how this makes sense for n particles in a box vs n particles as a brain as there is marked entropy difference, but what about a dead brain vs an alive brain with same n particles. The alive brain has at least 1 additional DOF (having a conscious state) yet n is the same. Harder to work in the secondlaw as a distinguishing characteristic in this example I know, but just say you stumble upon the two.

Comment: And is it always the case that higher entropy -> fewer DOF?